# "setting an array element with a sequence" exception when calling fit()

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am trying to perform a binary classification in which the input (features) are a sentence and some integer values. I convert the sentence to a tfidf vector before passing it into the classifier.

When I call the 'fit' method, I encounter a "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence" exception

I created a sample program to demonstrate the error:

```py
        data = {'xMessage': ['There was a farmer who had a dog',
                             'The mouse ran up the clock',
                             'Mary had a little lamb',
                             'The itsy bitsy spider',
                             'Brother John, Brother John! Morning bells are ringing!',
                             'My dame has lost her shoe',
                             'All the kings horses and all the Kings men',
                             'Im a little teapot',
                             'Jack and Jill went up the hill',
                             'How does your garden grow?'],
                'x01': [20, 21, 19, 18, 34, 22, 33, 22, 11, 32],
                'x02': [0, 10, 10, 12, 34, 43, 12, 0, 0, 54],
                'y': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
                }
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        self.train, self.test = train_test_split(self.df, test_size=0.3, shuffle=True)

        vec = TfidfVectorizer()
        vec.fit(self.df.xMessage)
        transformTrain = vec.transform(self.train.xMessage)
        self.train['messageVect'] = list(transformTrain)
        transformTest = vec.transform(self.test.xMessage)
        self.test['messageVect'] = list(transformTest)

        self.X_train = self.train[['messageVect',
                                   'x01', 'x02']]
        self.X_test = self.test[['messageVect',
                                 'x01', 'x02']]
        self.y_train = self.train['y']
        self.y_test = self.test['y']

        model = GaussianNB()
        model.fit(self.X_train,self.y_train)
        predicted= model.predict(self.X_test, self.y_test)
        y_true, y_pred = self.y_test, model.predict(self.X_test)
        print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
```

I'm new to this so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This error comes up when you try to set a single element of an `ndarray` with a sequence of values. I.e., given an array `x` with shape `(5,)`, calling something like `x[0] = (0, 1)` will raise this error. It's hard to see from the code you've posted, but my guess is that `self.X_train` has one level of nesting too many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to resolve the issue (or I hope I did). The working code is below. Let me know if it can be further improved!

```
        data = {'xMessage': ['There was a farmer who had a dog',
                         'The mouse ran up the clock',
                         'Mary had a little lamb',
                         'The itsy bitsy spider',
                         'Brother John, Brother John! Morning bells are ringing!',
                         'My dame has lost her shoe',
                         'All the kings horses and all the Kings men',
                         'Im a little teapot',
                         'Jack and Jill went up the hill',
                         'How does your garden grow?'],
            'x01': [20, 21, 19, 18, 34, 22, 33, 22, 11, 32],
            'x02': [0, 10, 10, 12, 34, 43, 12, 0, 0, 54],
            'y': [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
            }

    df=pd.DataFrame(data)

    vec = TfidfVectorizer()
    df_text = pd.DataFrame(vec.fit_transform(df['xMessage']).toarray())
    self.X_train,self.X_test, self.y_train, self.y_test = train_test_split(pd.concat([df[['x01','x02']],df_text],axis=1),df[['y']], test_size=0.3, shuffle=True)

    model = GaussianNB()
    model.fit(self.X_train,self.y_train)
    y_true, y_pred = self.y_test, model.predict(self.X_test)
    print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
```

Note: [This post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/38267/binary-text-classification-with-tfidfvectorizer-gives-valueerror-setting-an-arr) was of immense help.